# How to deploy parts of ExperienceBundle from source with package.xml (-x option)

Tags: community, salesforcedx, deployment

I have enabled the [ExperienceBundle metadata type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm) and am using [SFDX-git-delta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-git-delta) to generate package.xml files. SFDX-git-delta will generate a package.xml file like the following when one of the files in the experiences directory changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>CommunityMdName</members>
        <name>ExperienceBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

When I run `sfdx force:source:deploy -x myPackage.xml -u user@user.org` nothing is deployed.

1. How can I get a package.xml based deployment to deploy the ExperienceBundle?
2. Is it possible to only deploy the changes in the ExeperienceBundle while using the package.xml / -x (e.g., 3 view json files were changed, so only deploy those?)

I debugged with `export SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=metadata` and see that the package.xml file that sfdx generates (note this is not the one sfdx-git-delta creates) doesn't include the ExperienceBundle type, despite it being in the source package.xml (the one sfdx-git-delta creates) and the source folder (main/default/experiences/CommunityMdName/..). SFDX also doesn't copy over the experiences directory.

I would really like to be able to use SFDX-git-delta + ExperienceBundle metadata.

*Sidenote: It deploys fine when doing from the source directly with no package.xml, i.e., when using the -p option*

Comment: Is there actual metadata being produced after using git-delta?

Comment: The sfdx-git-delta produces the package.xml file to use as the -x package.xml file. The ExperienceBundle information is in the experiences source folder in the source format that has json files for everything instead of one giant binary.

Comment: Understood. I just wasn't sure if Git-Delta was also responsible for actually producing the metadata or just package.xml. Since you were saying "nothing is being deployed" just wanted to make sure there was actual metadata. And to clarify, I was able to deploy an Experience Bundle with packge.xml just now as well. Double check the site name to make sure it is correct

Comment: Try including `Network`, `Site` folder. From what I remember `ExperienceBundle` is just a replacement for `SiteDotCom`

Comment: @ytiq - added those 2 and they both show up in the intermediate sfdx metadata internal directory, but still not the experiences directory.

Answer (score 4):

Delta deploys for the Experience Bundle is not supported as of today!

You have to deploy the whole bundle along with the Network and Sitedotcom and other related metadata (like if you have objects and fields and lightning pages referencing it) to the Experience Bundle!

As far as `package.xml` is concerned this might be a bug in the CLI where the experiences directory is ignored.